# SQL Bing XML data - @Responsetext always null

Tags: xml, bing-api

I've created a proc that should retrieve TravelDistance from Bing's xml data but @ResponseText is always NULL. I'm able to get it to work with Google but not Bing. I've hardcoded the example from Bing's API website and I can see the XML and @ServiceUrl but

`Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT`

provides a value for @Object and only NULL for @ResponseText

```
`    Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as nvarchar(max);
Declare @serviceUrl as varchar(max)

  --set @serviceUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=' +@ToAddress+@ToCity+@ToState+@ToPostCode+
  -- '&destinations=' +@FromAddress+@FromCity+@FromState+ @FromPostCode +'&mode=driving&language=en-EN&units=imperial;'
  set @serviceUrl = 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/Truck?wp.0=590%20Crane%20Ave%2C%20Pittsburgh%2C%20PA&wp.1=600%20Forbes%20Ave%2C%20Pittsburgh%2C%20PA&vehicleHazardousMaterials=Flammable&output=xml&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                @serviceUrl, --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
declare @result table(data text)


Declare @Response as XML
SELECT @Response response, @ResponseText responsetext,@serviceUrl serviceurl
Select @ResponseText as XMLList

SET @Response = CAST(@ResponseText AS XML);

  Declare @Status as varchar(20)
   Declare @Distance as varchar(20)
   Declare @Time as varchar(20)

--  
set @Status= @Response.value('(Response/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Route/BoundingBox/TravelDistance)[1]', 'varchar(20)') 
  print @Status
  if(@Status='ZERO_RESULTS')

   Begin

                     set @Distance=@Status
   End
   else

   Begin
--   set @Distance=@Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text)[1]', 'varchar(20)') 
    set @Distance=@Response.value('(Response/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Route/BoundingBox/TravelDistance)[1]','varchar(20)')
 --     set @Time=@Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/duration/text)[1]', 'varchar(20)') 
   End
--  Select @Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Distance 
--  select (cast(replace(@Distance,' km','') as numeric)/2) + ((cast(replace(@Distance,' km','') as numeric)/2)/4) as Distance, @Time as Time
    select @Distance as Distance`
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How big are the responses? `sp_OAMethod` looks to have a size restriction on what it can handle.

Comment: The size is excessively large. How can I work around the restriction?